# Is there a term for this programming thing?

Tags: terminology

The thing in question in a derpy example:

JS:

```
var length = 5;

for ( var i = 1; i < length + 1; i++ ) {
    $( '#element' + (i -1) ).fadeOut( 500 );
    $( '#element' + i ).fadeIn( 500 );
}
```

HTML:

```
<div id="element1" style="height: 100px; width: 100px; background-color: red;"></div>
<div id="element2" style="height: 100px; width: 100px; background-color: green;"></div>
<div id="element3" style="height: 100px; width: 100px; background-color: blue;"></div>
<div id="element4" style="height: 100px; width: 100px; background-color: yellow;"></div>
<div id="element5" style="height: 100px; width: 100px; background-color: pink;"></div>
```

Is there a term for this? I guess the 'thing' that I'm talking about, in sentence form, is: **"dynamically targetting an object in a loop by name using the incramenting loop variable as a part of the variable name you're targetting"**.

Probably explaining this poorly. Does anyone understand what I'm asking, and is there a 'term' for this in programming?

Comment: sorry to say, but no name..

Comment: It's not efficient and unprofessional, therefore doesn't deserve a name.

Comment: why is `i` initialized at 1? Wouldn't zero suffice.

Comment: @u54r : why? ( curious what makes it bad practice / unprofessional / inefficient )

Comment: @agconti : just a derpy example because I don't normally number DOM elements zero-based, so for the dynamic identifier to work I just add 1 to the `length` and start `i` at `1`.

Comment: That HTML made me wince. The use of 'style' attributes. The redundancy when 2/3 of the style expressed is redundant and so could be expressed more compactly by making the elements members of the same class, with one CSS rule for height and width... I know that's completely irrelevant to the question's main issue, hence comment.

Comment: @root: dude... this isn't code that exists anywhere but this question nor would I ever implement anything like that in production code. I wrote it in 2 seconds in the quickest way possible just for the sake of an example in the stackoverflow question... chill lol.

Comment: @SamuelStiles thanks, I was curious.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The phrase that most programmers will understand is "dynamic variable name".

Comment: Is a DOM element ID really a variable name? I suppose it's analogous in a way.

Comment: Yep, fair point.  Would you prefer if I said "dynamic identifier"?